# Display no of view count of the product from view_product table

Tags: php, json, pdo

I can able to display list of product, but I want to show no of view count of the product from the view_product table

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("Select pro_id,product, description,qty from product_tbl");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt-> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$user_arr=array('data'=>$row);
echo json_encode($user_arr);
```

Based on product_id I want to view count of each product from the view_product table, how can I use the below query in PDO json encode.

```
select count(id) as count1 from view_product where user_id=".$row['pro_id'].";
```

Expected Output as below

```
------------------------------------------------
pro_id  |  product  | description  | view count
------------------------------------------------
1       |  prodcut1 | description  | 199
------------------------------------------------
2       |  prodcut2 |  description | 124
------------------------------------------------
```